# Web hook listener in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webhooks

I am writing a simple monitoring system for one of our existing production system. The system being monitored is a SMPP gateway. The basic requirement is to send a message to the SMPP gateway at a given frequency and receive the message via a web hook. This is so to ensure that the SMPP gateway is functioning as expected else email alarms are triggered.

This is the flow my program:

- Connect to SMPP gateway
- Start a web hook listener on a new thread (server)
- Send a test message
- Listen for incoming web hooks and notify the parent thread via events
- If message web hook was received, exit gracefully, else trigger email alarm.

I have implemented this system in AWS Lambda and assigned a elastic IP by placing the Lambda function inside a VPC. I am able to send the message to SMPP gateway and the gateway is attempting to respond via web hook. But unfortunately, the server can't reach the web hook listener via the specified elastic IP. I searched around and figured that one way to implement web hook listener in AWS Lambda is by using an API gateway trigger. This is not use because this will not gaurantee that the same Lambda instance which sent the message via SMPP will receive the web hook request.

So my question is, is it possible to run a web hook listener in AWS Lambda and receive requests via an attached elastic IP?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, do you want have a lambda function online and listening to a web hook? Is it online at certain times or always?

Comment: Hey. It's online for a certain period (5 min). During that period, it listens on a specific web hook. I want to know if I can access the 'online' lambda by calling the web hook URL?

Comment: I think Michael was on-point there, Lambda functions aren't built to work this way. Maybe a spot ec2 instance (or an on-demand that you turn on and off from a lambda function) can fit what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to run a web hook listener in AWS Lambda and receive requests via an attached elastic IP.

Lambda functions inside a VPC make outbound requests to the Internet using an Elastic IP attached to a NAT Gateway, via an ENI associated with the container host.  Neither the ENI nor the EIP are exclusively bound to one single Lambda invocation.  Lambda functions are technically allowed to listen for inbound connections... but they will never arrive via the ENI, and the NAT Gateway is also specifically designed not to allow connections initiated from outside to make their way back in.  So there are at least two layers of the design that prevent what you are attempting from being done in this way.

Comment: Thank you, I have split mine responsibilities into multiple Lambda functions and using an API Gateway to listen to webhook calls and using DynamoDB to maintain state.